# bin file in eclipse or notepad

Tags: eclipse, notepad, bin

Whenever I tried to open the .bin file in Windows, (and also eclipse), it is like this, so I cannot read anything. I am using it to test Buffer Pool, but I cannot read, so I cannot know that is the test was successful or not. It is same when I opened it wil notepad.

I am using U.S. window, but installed Korean language, but I still can read/write English well.

[image: this is the screen shot when I opend the bin file]

Answer (score 1):

Extension of file name ".bin" stands for "BINARY". That means your file may contain not-printable characters as you saw.

If you want to see the contenst of binary files, you should use 'Hexadecimal Editor', 'hex editor' in short, instead of text editor like notepad.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_hex_editors shows many hex editors.

Some software may be able to handle your .bin files. It depends that the origin of that file.